# Summary statistics using ddply

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I like to write a function using `ddply` that outputs the summary statistics based on the name of two columns of `data.frame` `mat`.

- `mat` is a big `data.frame` with the name of columns `"metric", "length", "species", "tree", ...,"index"`
- `index` is factor with 2 levels `"Short", "Long"`
- `"metric", "length", "species", "tree"` and others are all continuous variables

Function:

```
summary1 <- function(arg1,arg2) {
    ...

    ss <- ddply(mat, .(index), function(X) data.frame(
        arg1 = as.list(summary(X$arg1)),
        arg2 = as.list(summary(X$arg2)),
        .parallel = FALSE)

    ss
}
```

I expect the output to look like this after calling `summary1("metric","length")`

```
Short metric.Min. metric.1st.Qu. metric.Median metric.Mean metric.3rd.Qu. metric.Max. length.Min. length.1st.Qu. length
.Median length.Mean length.3rd.Qu. length.Max. 

....

Long metric.Min. metric.1st.Qu. metric.Median metric.Mean metric.3rd.Qu. metric.Max. length.Min. length.1st.Qu. length
.Median length.Mean length.3rd.Qu. length.Max.

....
```

At the moment the function does not produce the desired output? What modification should be made here?

Thanks for your help.

---

Here is a toy example

```
mat <- data.frame(
    metric = rpois(10,10), length = rpois(10,10), species = rpois(10,10),
    tree = rpois(10,10), index = c(rep("Short",5),rep("Long",5))
)
```

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you provided sample data (prefereably with `dput`).

Comment: @Richie- Here is a toy example `mat<-data.frame(metric=rpois(10,10),length=rpois(10,10),species=rpois(10,10),tree=rpois(10,10),index=c(rep("Short",5),rep("Long",5)))`- Thanks

Comment: You could edit question to add sample data instead of writing a comment (I done it for you ;)).

Comment: I would suggest making your function more generalizable by passing in additional parameters for the `data.frame` and the variable to split by as well. That way your function will work when you need to use it on a data.frame named `Mat` or `MAT` or `MyOtherData`, etc.

Comment: There should be an R generic function for that. Even supporting any number of arguments. Is there such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Nick wrote in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714658/summary-statistics-using-ddply/5715342#5715342) you can't use `$` to reference variable passed as character name. When you wrote `X$arg1` then `R` search for column named `"arg1"` in `data.frame` `X`. You can reference to it either by `X[,arg1]` or `X[[arg1]]`.

And if you want nicely named output I propose below solution:

```
summary1 <- function(arg1, arg2) {

    ss <- ddply(mat, .(index), function(X) data.frame(
        setNames(
            list(as.list(summary(X[[arg1]])), as.list(summary(X[[arg2]]))),
            c(arg1,arg2)
            )), .parallel = FALSE)

    ss
}
summary1("metric","length")
```

Output for toy data is:

```
  index metric.Min. metric.1st.Qu. metric.Median metric.Mean metric.3rd.Qu.
1  Long           5              7            10         8.6             10
2 Short           7              7             9         8.8             10
  metric.Max. length.Min. length.1st.Qu. length.Median length.Mean length.3rd.Qu.
1          11           9             10            11        10.8             12
2          11           4              9             9         9.0             11
  length.Max.
1          12
2          12
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this more like what you want?

```
summary1 <- function(arg1,arg2) {
ss <- ddply(mat, .(index), function(X){ data.frame(
    arg1 = as.list(summary(X[,arg1])),
    arg2 = as.list(summary(X[,arg2])),
    .parallel = FALSE)})
ss
}
```