# Summary statistics by two or more factor variables?

Tags: r, summary

This is best illustrated with an example

```
str(mtcars)
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear, labels=c("three","four","five"))
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels=c("four","six","eight"))
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am, labels=c("manual","auto")
str(mtcars)
tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$gear, sum)
```

That gives me the summed mpg per gear. But say I wanted a 3x3 table with gear across the top and cyl down the side, and 9 cells with the bivariate sums in, how would I get that 'smartly'.

I could go.

```
tapply(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl=="four"], mtcars$gear[mtcars$cyl=="four"], sum)
tapply(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl=="six"], mtcars$gear[mtcars$cyl=="six"], sum)
tapply(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$cyl=="eight"], mtcars$gear[mtcars$cyl=="eight"], sum)
```

This seems cumbersome.

Then how would I bring a 3rd variable in the mix?

This is somewhat in the space I'm thinking about.
[Summary statistics using ddply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714658/summary-statistics-using-ddply)

**update** This gets me there, but it's not pretty.

```
aggregate(mpg ~ am+cyl+gear, mtcars,sum)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 41):

How about this, still using `tapply()`? It's more versatile than you knew!

```
with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, list(cyl, gear), sum))
#       three  four five
# four   21.5 215.4 56.4
# six    39.5  79.0 19.7
# eight 180.6    NA 30.8
```

Or, if you'd like the printed output to be a bit more interpretable:

```
with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, list("Cylinder#"=cyl, "Gear#"=gear), sum))
```

---

If you want to use more than two cross-classifying variables, the idea's exactly the same. The results will then be returned in a 3-or-more-dimensional array:

```
A <- with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, list(cyl, gear, carb), sum))

dim(A)
# [1] 3 3 6
lapply(1:6, function(i) A[,,i]) # To convert results to a list of matrices

# But eventually, the curse of dimensionality will begin to kick in...
table(is.na(A))
# FALSE  TRUE 
#    12    42
```

Comment: This would seem to be the obvious answer, considering that tapply with one factor was the starting point. `ftable` might also be of interest.

Answer (score 9):

I think the answers already on this question are fantastic options, but I wanted to share an additional option based on the `dplyr` package (this came up for me because I'm teaching a class right now where we use `dplyr` for data manipulation, so I wanted to avoid introducing students to specialized base R functions like `tapply` or `aggregate`).

You can group on as many variables as you want using the `group_by` function and then summarize information from these groups with `summarize`. I think this code is more readable to an R newcomer than the formula-based interface of `aggregate`, yielding identical results:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am, cyl, gear) %>%
  summarize(mpg=sum(mpg))
#       am   cyl  gear   mpg
#    (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1      0     4     3  21.5
# 2      0     4     4  47.2
# 3      0     6     3  39.5
# 4      0     6     4  37.0
# 5      0     8     3 180.6
# 6      1     4     4 168.2
# 7      1     4     5  56.4
# 8      1     6     4  42.0
# 9      1     6     5  19.7
# 10     1     8     5  30.8
```

With two variables, you can summarize with one variable on the rows and the other on the columns by adding a call to the `spread` function from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  summarize(mpg=sum(mpg)) %>%
  spread(gear, mpg)
#     cyl     3     4     5
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1     4  21.5 215.4  56.4
# 2     6  39.5  79.0  19.7
# 3     8 180.6    NA  30.8
```

Comment: What does the %>% mean?

Comment: @HermanToothrot you can read up on it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536154/what-does-mean-in-r

Answer (score 4):

I like Josh's answer for this, but `reshape2` can also provide a nice framework for these type of problems:

```
library(reshape2)

#use subset to only grab the variables of interest...
mtcars.m <- melt(subset(mtcars, select = c("mpg", "gear", "cyl")), measure.vars="mpg")
#cast into appropriate format
dcast(mtcars.m, cyl ~ gear, fun.aggregate=sum, value.var="value")

   cyl three  four five
1  four  21.5 215.4 56.4
2   six  39.5  79.0 19.7
3 eight 180.6   0.0 30.8
```

Comment: I edited to put quotes around the `"mpg"` passed to `measure.vars`, b/c the code wasn't otherwise working for me. Does that look right to you too? Also, is there any easy way to get this to return `NA` rather than `0` in the middle of the bottom row?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - very strange, I have no idea why that worked previously without quotes around mpg...thanks for that. Also, the `fill` parameter to `dcast` should allow NA's, but I'm getting a strange error...setting `fill = Inf` or any other numeric value works though. This is not what I'd expect from the function...will dig further

Answer (score 3):

The answer contains same output using tapply and aggregate function.

I would like to add some information to Josh O'Brien's answer. User can either use aggregate function or tapply depending on output. In order to use more than one factor variable in tapply one can use the method Josh has shown.

Loading dataset

```
data("mtcars")
```

Using tapply

```
with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, list("Cylinder#"=cyl, "Gear#"=gear), sum))
```

The output of above code is

```
        Gear#
Cylinder#     3     4    5
    4     21.5 215.4 56.4
    6     39.5  79.0 19.7
    8    180.6    NA 30.8
```

Using aggregate function

```
with(mtcars, aggregate(mpg, list(Cylinder = cyl, Gear =  gear), sum))
```

Output of aggregate function

```
    Cylinder Gear  x
1        4    3  21.5
2        6    3  39.5
3        8    3 180.6
4        4    4 215.4
5        6    4  79.0
6        4    5  56.4
7        6    5  19.7
8        8    5  30.8
```

Now if the user wants same output as aggregate function but using tapply.

```
as.data.frame(as.table(with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, list("Cylinder#"=cyl, "Gear#"=gear),
sum))))
```

Output of tapply function

```
   Cylinder. Gear.  Freq
1         4     3  21.5
2         6     3  39.5
3         8     3 180.6
4         4     4 215.4
5         6     4  79.0
6         8     4    NA
7         4     5  56.4
8         6     5  19.7
9         8     5  30.8
```

NA's can be kept or removed as per business requirements.