# What does %>% mean in R

Tags: r, magrittr

I am following this example, the *server.R*, [file is here](https://github.com/wch/movies/blob/master/server.R#L32).

I plan to do a similar filter, but am lost as to what `%>%` does.

```
 # Apply filters
    m <- all_movies %>%
      filter(
        Reviews >= reviews,
        Oscars >= oscars,
        Year >= minyear,
        Year <= maxyear,
        BoxOffice >= minboxoffice,
        BoxOffice <= maxboxoffice
      ) %>%
      arrange(Oscars)
```

Comment: See [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html), which is being used heavily in **dplyr**.

Comment: It has no meaning in R.  The magrittr package (used by dplyr) defines a meaning for it: http://cran.r-project.org/package=magrittr

Comment: Take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125672/what-does-function-mean-in-r?noredirect=1#comment53064401_27125672

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does %>% function mean in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27125672/1255289)

Answer (score 384, accepted):

The infix operator `%>%` is not part of base R, but is in fact defined by the package `magrittr` ([CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html)) and is heavily used by `dplyr` ([CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html)).

It works like a pipe, hence the reference to Magritte's famous painting [The Treachery of Images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceci_n%27est_pas_une_pipe).

What the function does is to pass the left hand side of the operator to the first argument of the right hand side of the operator. In the following example, the data frame `iris` gets passed to `head()`:

```
library(magrittr)
iris %>% head()
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Thus, `iris %>% head()` is equivalent to `head(iris)`.

Often, `%>%` is called multiple times to "chain" functions together, which accomplishes the same result as nesting. For example in the chain below, `iris` is passed to `head()`, then the result of that is passed to `summary()`.

```
iris %>% head() %>% summary()
```

Thus `iris %>% head() %>% summary()` is equivalent to `summary(head(iris))`. Some people prefer chaining to nesting because the functions applied can be read from left to right rather than from inside out.

Comment: Can we override this %>% operator with unix | in R?

Comment: I imagine you could, but it would probably interfere with the use of the | operator for "or", which is sometimes needed.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question but I'm curious how does `%>%` reference The Treachery of Images asides from being called literally a pipe? The pipe operator is well known in bash scripting so I thought that was what it was referencing that?

Comment: @NullSalad The Treachery of Images is simply quoted in the package description, apparently as mere wordplay, see here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html

Comment: Nicely explained! I still want to know, though: when is it best practice to use %>% instead of just nesting functions? Is there some convention for when each syntax ought to be used?

Comment: Why use something that "works like a pipe but is not a pipe" instead of just using a pipe directly?

Comment: Scientists, I do not find another explanation for this ._.