# How to use binary operators without overwriting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Inspired by the use of `+` operator by `ggplot()` and `gganimate()`, I was wondering how the `+` operator can be used for other use especially using it for strings like python.

I know I can overwrite these infix operators using `` `+` <- function(...) something `` but that completely overwrites the function, now I cannot use it for regular use like summing numbers.

Also I am more interested in knowing the internals i.e. how `ggplot()` managed to use `+` for their use without overwriting it. If anyone can explain it, I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how the `+` operator is implemented in ggplot by doing:

```r
> ggplot2:::`+.gg`

function (e1, e2) 
{
    if (missing(e2)) {
        abort("Cannot use `+.gg()` with a single argument. Did you accidentally put + on a new line?")
    }
    e2name <- deparse(substitute(e2))
    if (is.theme(e1)) 
        add_theme(e1, e2, e2name)
    else if (is.ggplot(e1)) 
        add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name)
    else if (is.ggproto(e1)) {
        abort("Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?")
    }
}
```

You can see that this uses S3 class-based dispatch.

It is possible to do the same thing for character strings if you reclass them as a bespoke class with its own methods, as you can read about [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730551/making-a-string-concatenation-operator-in-r)

A minimal example of getting your own class to behave in an analogous fashion to ggplot would be something like:

```r
`+.weirdclass` <- function(e1, e2) paste(e1, e2)

weirdclass <- function(x) structure(x, class = "weirdclass")

weirdclass("hello") +
  weirdclass("world")
#> [1] "hello world"
```

Comment: Thanks, this does answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate strings in R, you can use either the paste()/paste0() base R functions or the str_c() function from the stringr package.

This post is also relevant to the ggplot2 part of your query: [What is the difference between the "+" operator in ggplot2 and the "%>%" operator in magrittr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332861/what-is-the-difference-between-the-operator-in-ggplot2-and-the-operato)