# R: Create a list of functions calls

Tags: r, dplyr, kaggle

I'm trying to understand a little more about R and came across this really good script here on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/msjgriffiths/d/kaggle/sf-salaries/explore-sf-salary-data/code

I'm a beginner in R and I'm struggling to understand a portion of the code the poster used which is summarised below:

```
data_csv <- read_csv("../Salaries.csv", na=c("Not Provided"))
data <- data_csv
glimpse(data_csv)
non_numeric_vars <- names(data)[!sapply(data, is.numeric)]
data %>%
  select(one_of(non_numeric_vars)) %>%
summarise_each(funs(unique_vars = length(unique(.))))
```

The selection I'm not understanding is the `funs` function in the code above. If I read the R docs for dplyr, it says it needs a list of functions specified by the 3 arguments. Where are the three arguments or has it been piped in as per this thread [What does %>% mean in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536154/what-does-mean-in-r)?

Also I tried to find the docs for `unique_vars` but came up with nothing. I'm not sure where I can read more about this variable?

```
funs {dplyr}    R Documentation Create a list of functions calls.

Description

funs provides a flexible way to generate a named list of functions for input to other functions like summarise_each.

Usage

funs(...)

funs_(dots) Arguments

dots,...     A list of functions specified by: Their name, "mean" The function itself, mean A call to the function with . as a dummy parameter, mean(., na.rm = TRUE) Examples

funs(mean, "mean", mean(., na.rm = TRUE))

# Overide default names funs(m1 = mean, m2 = "mean", m3 = mean(., na.rm = TRUE))

# If you have function names in a vector, use funs_ fs <- c("min", "max") funs_(fs)
```

The result after running his code is below - not sure where the unique_vars variable comes in in his results:

```
## Source: local data frame [1 x 6]
## 
##   EmployeeName JobTitle Benefits Notes Agency Status
##          (int)    (int)    (int) (int)  (int)  (int)
## 1       110811     2159    98648     1      1      3
```

Comment: `unique_vars` is not a function; it's a parameter name the programmer is creating for a value. The programmer is just getting the number of unique values for each categorical variable.

Comment: @42, but the result doesn't show a row that says unique_vars, why name it if you cannot see it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

`funs` doesn't need 3 arguments. In the documentation, where it says

> A list of functions specified by: Their name, "mean" The function itself, mean A call to the function with . as a dummy parameter, mean(., na.rm = TRUE)

This is 3 different ways to format your arguments to `funs`. Each argument to `funs` is interpreted as a function.

`unique_vars = length(unique(.))` labels the output of summarizing by `length(unique(.))` as a column called "unique_vars".