# What does the %<>% operator mean in R?

Tags: r, magrittr

1. What does the `%<>%` operator do in R ?
2. What's the difference between using `%<>%` and `<-` ?
3. In what type of circumstances `%<>%` could be useful ?

Comment: It is similar to `:=` in data.table.

Comment: @akrun does it update in-place? it is the whole point of `:=`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does %>% mean in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536154/what-does-mean-in-r)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The help, `` ?magrittr::`%<>%` ``, answers all your questions, if you are refering to magrittr`s compound assignment pipe-operator:

> [...] `%<>%` is used to update a value
>   by first piping it into one or more rhs expressions, and then
>   assigning the result. For example, `some_object %<>% foo %>% bar` is
>   equivalent to `some_object <- some_object %>% foo %>% bar`. It must be
>   the first pipe-operator in a chain, but otherwise it works like `%>%`.

So

```
library(magrittr)
set.seed(1);x <- rnorm(5)
x %<>% abs %>% sort
x
# [1] 0.1836433 0.3295078 0.6264538 0.8356286 1.5952808
```

is the same as

```
set.seed(1);x <- rnorm(5)
x <- sort(abs(x))
x
# [1] 0.1836433 0.3295078 0.6264538 0.8356286 1.5952808
```