# Aggregate based on year and ID in R

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I would like to aggregate my costs by `year` and by `ID`.

Here is some example data:

```
   ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
   year <- c(1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
   cost <- c(1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2)

   data = cbind(ID, year, cost)
```

This information should be saved in additional column so `costs_year1`, `costs_year2`, `costs_year3` by `ID`. Then, I would drop the other columns and remove the duplicate IDs so I have a wide dataframe.

Any suggestions to do this neatly?

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3)
year <- c(1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
cost <- c(1,1,2,3,2,2,2,2)

data = data.frame(ID, year, cost)

data %>%
  mutate(year = paste0("costs_year",year)) %>%
  group_by(year,ID) %>%
  summarize_at("cost",sum) %>%
  spread(year,cost)

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#      ID costs_year1 costs_year2 costs_year3
# * <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     1           1           6          NA
# 2     2          NA          NA           4
# 3     3          NA          NA           4
```

`%>%` is called the pipe operator, it's from package `magrittr` and you can use it (for example) after attaching `tidyverse` with `library(tidyverse)`.

Using pipes you can use the output of the preceding instruction as a first parameter of your next call, but examples will teach you better. Here's how to make it work without pipes:

```
x <- mutate(data, year = paste0("costs_year",year))
x <- group_by(x,year,ID)
x <- summarize_at(x,"cost",sum)
spread(x,year,cost)
```

For more info : [What does %>% mean in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536154/what-does-mean-in-r)

Comment: I think he wants to have sum rather than mean, which could be obtained by replacing `sum` with `mean` as you would also tell. Great `tidy` answer!

Comment: Je vous en prie

Comment: What does this %>% mean?  And yes, I meant sum not mean

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if something is still unclear

Answer (score 0):

Using `dcast()` of `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
df.wide <- dcast(df1, ID ~ year, sum)
names(df.wide) <- c("ID", paste0("costs.year.", 1:3))
```

Or in one step:

```
df.wide <- setNames(dcast(df1, ID ~ year, sum), c("ID", paste0("costs.year.", 1:3)))
```

***Yielding***

```
> df.wide
  ID costs.year.1 costs.year.2 costs.year.3
1  1            1            6            0
2  2            0            0            4
3  3            0            0            4
```

***Data***

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), year = c(1, 2, 
                                                                2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), cost = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                          -8L))
```